# Securing Cloudfront using Cognito IDToken

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

Hi my website is hosted though cloudfront by using s3. Is there a way to secure access to my cloudfront using id token from my cognito user pool?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security), maybe?